# Using python's argparse, is it possible to specify C style command line arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse. Let's say i want to run a python script with 2 mandatory arguments and for each argument, i also include the option (-flag). Something like below:

```
$ python test.py -arg1 abc -arg2 xyz
```

Also, is it possible to allow 2 flag names (short and long names) say -arg1 and -a1?

Comment: Mandatory arguments should be positional: `test.py abc xyz`. It is troubling to identify mandatory arguments from the named argumens in the usage listing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
parser.add_argument('--abc', '-a', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--xyz', '-x', required=True)
```